# Sort array by other array?

Tags: ios, arrays, sorting, swift3

I'm wondering how to sort an array by another array in Swift 3

let's say I have :

```
struct Channel {
    var id: Int
}

let channel1 = Channel(id: 1)
let channel2 = Channel(id: 2)
let channel3 = Channel(id: 3)
let channel4 = Channel(id: 4)
let channel5 = Channel(id: 5)

var original = [channel1, channel2, channel3, channel4, channel5]
var favorites = [channel3, channel2, channel1, channel4]
```

and I want to sort the original array to be :

```
[channel3, channel2, channel1, channel4, channel5]
```

Is there any quick and low consuming way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
favorites.append(contentsOf: original.filter { chanel in
    !favorites.contains(where: { $0.id == chanel.id })
})
```

Comment: Well, that was simple enough ! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Zip is much easy method to achieve this

```
// use zip to combine the two arrays and sort that based on the first
// Your original array

let combined = zip(array1, array2).sort {$0.0 < $1.0}
print(combined) //  

// Now use map to extract the individual arrays    
let sorted1 = combined.map {$0.0}
let sorted2 = combined.map {$0.1}
```

Hope it helps